# How to conditinally create a field in an array during initialization?

Tags: php, php-7

Consider this code:

```
$foo = [
    'x' => 'asdf',
    'y' => $bar,
];
```

What I want is that if `$bar` is null, then the field `'y'` should not even be created. I know that I can create `$foo` first and then manually add `'y'` conditionally, alternatively remove all null fields afterwards. But that looks ugly. Essentially something like this:

```
$foo = [
    'x' => 'asdf',
    if($bar !== null) 'y' => $bar,
];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @CBroe Fair enough. Wanna write an answer?